# What the does the line if a = b mean in ruby code?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am trying to understand a particular line in the following piece of code:

```
def roman_to_integer(roman_string)
   prev = nil
   roman_string.to_s.upcase.split(//).reverse.inject(0) do
    |running_sum, digit|
     if digit_value = DIGITS[digit]
       if prev && prev > digit_value
         running_sum -= digit_value
       else
         running_sum += digit_value
       end
       prev = digit_value
     end
     running_sum
   end
 end
```

Can someone please help me understand when the line if digit_value = DIGITS[digit] means? are we assigning the value corresponding to the key 'DIGIT' from the hash to the digit_value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are we assigning the value

Yes, we are. And we also check the truthiness of the operation. Assignment operator returns the value that was assigned. Now, if it was a digit, it will be a truthy result and control will enter the `if`.

If `DIGITS[digit]` returns nil or false, it will be assigned to `digit_value` and also it will also become result of the assignment operation. Those values are falsey, so we would enter the `else`, if we had one there. But we don't, so we just skip the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

> are we assigning the value corresponding to the key 'DIGIT' from the hash to the digit_value here?

Yes that is exactly what is happening. The temporary variable is slightly easier to read than the extraction from the hash. In similar circumstances, obtaining the value might be more expensive (think of a database read for example instead of a Hash lookup), so it is not a bad practice to get into.

The assignment operator also returns the value assigned for the `if` statement to work.

Alternative equivalent syntax is a bit more verbose:

```
digit_value = DIGITS[digit]
if digit_value
  # .... etc
```

so this is also a common style choice when assigning a value to a variable and wanting to check its truthiness immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`if digit_value = DIGITS[digit]` will return true `if DIGITS[digit]` has value other than `nil` or `false`. This is because in Ruby nil and false are the only values that are considered falsy.

Ruby will first assign the value to variable and than evaluate if the value is falsy.